# Creating NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to do a fetch on an entity for "Contractor". Contractor has a one-to-many relationship with another entity called "Job". So a contractor can have many jobs.

How would I create a NSSortDescriptor so my fetch is sorted by number of jobs the contractor has -- from greatest to least?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@count` collection operator. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"jobs.@count" ascending:NO]
```